# How to zoom and scroll an image using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

this is my Code. I want to be able to zoom in and out and scroll left right up down on image

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;height:650px;">
            <img  width="70%" style="float:right; position: absolute; top:5px; right:5px;" src="http://example.com/mypic/test.jpg">
        </div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
img {
transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

img:active {
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: and what have you tried ? this is not a 'code making' site

Comment: so far i just added the CSS i don't know if i have to add anything else

Comment: all i want it is adding a picture to a site and make it zoomable

Comment: I thought you wanted an animation.

Comment: for scrolling you use the css overflow property.
To zoom you want on active?

Comment: can you zoom and scroll ?

Answer (score 1):

Pan and zoom properties on an image using CSS would best be applied on a `:hover` state.

I have removed your inline styling and re-separated your CSS and HTML. Around the image is your original `div` with a `.zoom-img` class to style it from other `div` elements on your site.

```css
.zoom-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.zoom-img img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
}

.zoom-img img:hover {
  width: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/3000/3000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @keyframes in css.

Comment: John if I had time I would.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use @ keyframes to anime that. See in that code. Hope you solve that . :)

```
    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
}
```